# Resource errors in delphi

Tags: delphi

My project complied fine. But when I am running application in debug mode, I'm getting many runtime errors each time regarding resources. How can I resolve this?

**EDIT**

`the Actual error is "project raised exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource WW_DBN_PRIOR_ENABLED not found'`

Comment: EResNotFound with message 'Resource Not Found'

Comment: You need to link the resources that cannot be found.

Comment: As a word of advice, it's not helpful to say "I'm getting errors regarding resources". Instead give complete details including full error text.

Comment: the Actual error is "project raised exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource WW_DBN_PRIOR_ENABLED not found'".

Comment: Every time getting different exceptions for each execution.

Comment: Find out what code needs that resource and work out why it is not being linked. The error message tells you all you need to know.